# Game uses all Joystick ID#'s - how to make it use only the virtual joystick?

Tags: windows-10, emulator, xinput, joystick

I use a third-party controller (in my example it's Saitek P990). I was fine using it for quite some time because the games I played didn't detect my joystick at all and I was able to use it with either [x360ce](https://x360ce.com/) or [World of Joysticks xInput Emulator](https://worldofjoysticks.com/) which worked fine.

A certain game (CrossCode in this example), however, detects my P990 gamepad and works like expected except for the right thumbstick, -- vertical moves horizontal axis and horizontal movement does nothing. The game has no way of remapping joystick bindings in-game.

I tried fixing this with my usual method of virtual emulation. The [x360ce](https://x360ce.com/) method does nothing and next, I try the [WoJ](https://worldofjoysticks.com/) method. This time, I find that the game takes input from all joysticks simultaneously, thus a single button press results in a double-press in-game, and right thumbstick has a weird behavior. There is no way to select which gamepad the game should use in options. The game simply detects input from both P990 and emulated gamepad simultaneously.

Using [JoyID](https://theairtacticalassaultgroup.com/forum/showthread.php?t=13009) to switch the gamepad ID# reveals that the game uses all 16 ID numbers, and doesn't prioritize one over another, -- it simply uses all of them.

To disable the game taking input from the physical gamepad, I tried disabling the driver in windows device manager, but as I expected, it disables it for the emulator as well.

Using tools like [JoyToKey](https://joytokey.net/en/) or [vJoy](http://vjoystick.sourceforge.net/site/) is again no luck because the game still takes input from the physical joystick.

Is there a way to disable a joystick for one program and enable it for another? Is there something else I could try?

Comment: Sounds like you should [file a bug report on the CrossCode forum](https://steamcommunity.com/app/368340/discussions/1/).